# How to implement in code to save battery life but keep iphone application live?

Tags: iphone, keep-alive, battery, consumption

I have an iPhone application which does audio recording. What I want to achieve is to keep the application alive to do continuos recording but at the same time save battery life i.e. save power consumption

Just a note, I have used following code to keep application alive.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: Above code disable screen locking. But this will keep screen display on which is not needed & is display is off battery can be saved. BUt How do I achieve that. If the setIdleTimerDisabled is NO then it will lock the device & application will not be active.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to instantly 'save battery life'. Only thing you can probably do is minimize read/write operations, internet access etc. This you have to manually do in code.

Comment: My application only have audio recording. No internet access or no explicit read/write operation. 
Also please see my comment to question